# Probability problem clarification request

Tags: probability

> My dad heard this story on the radio. At Duke University, two students
>   had received A’s in chemistry all semester. But on the night before
>   the final exam, they were partying in another state and didn’t get
>   back to Duke until it was over. Their excuse to the professor was that
>   they had a flat tire, and they asked if they could take a make-up
>   test. The professor agreed, wrote out a test and sent the two to
>   separate rooms to take it. The first question (on one side of the
>   paper) was worth 5 points, and they answered it easily. Then they
>   flipped the paper over and found the second question, worth 95 points:
>   ‘Which tire was it?’ What was the probability that both students would
>   say the same thing? My dad and I think it’s 1 in 16. Is that right?

Answer:

(a) Assuming that the students did not actually have a flat tire and that each student gives any given tire as an answer with probability 1/4, then probability that they both give the same answer is 1/4. If the students actually had a flat tire, then the probability is 1 that they both give the same answer. So, if the probability that they actually had a flat tire is p, then the probability that they both give the same answer is $$\frac{1}{4}(1-p)+p=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}p$$

---

Could someone expound on how the formula was derived? (primary question)

Also I guess the easier way to see that 1\4 is the correct answer would be writing out all possible outcomes as ordered pairs, of which there will be 4 outcomes where the first term = the second term out of 16 total outcomes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a probability $p$ of having a flat tire, so they have a probability of $1-p$ of *not* having a flat tire.

If they have a flat tire, we assume the students know which tire it was, so the probability that they say the same tire is $1$.

If they do not have a flat tire, we assume that the students will choose a tire at random, in which case there is a $1/4$ probability that they will say the same tire (a way to see this is that the first student picks a tire, and then there is a 1/4 chance the other student picks the same one).

To get the same answer, one of two things has to happen: (1) they didn't have a flat, but said the same tire, or (2) they did have a flat and said the same tire.  Since these are mutually exclusive, we find the separate probabilities of their occurrence and sum to get the probability
$$
\frac{1}{4}(1-p)+p = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}p.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, I think I used a book that you co-authored(?) to self-study pre-calculus in 2014, which served as a stepping stone for my self-study of calculus later on. So I'd like to thank you for that too, it was helpful :)

Comment: So "1/4(1-p)" is like saying one fourth of the time they didn't have a flat tire, they will say the same tire. "p" is like saying out of p times they had a flat tire they will say the same tire p times. And we just sum that up. I understand now.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad to hear that book was useful: we still use it for our precalculus classes at the University of Washington. Cheers!